# How to stop React-Native FlatList Interfering with other components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a simple React-Native app that uses FlatList with Redux. The problem is that when the list becomes long and reaches the bottom of the screen where the input elements exists it disrupts these input elements even though they are in another component and container. I've tried a million fixes for this, but nothing seems to work.

How can I do something like only have FlatList occupy 2/3rds of the screen?

This is a screenshot of the issue (when the items reach the input boxes it results in the input boxes shrinking and being disrupted):

[image]

This is the app file that contains all my components:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
  <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ItemsList />
        <AddItem />
    </View>
  </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the component that uses FlatList:

```
class ItemsList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <List>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.items} 
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <ListItem 
                            name={item.item} id={item.id}
                        />
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString() }
                />
            </List>
          );

        }
    }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { items:  state.items };
  };


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemsList);
```

The code for addItem is:

```
class AddItem extends Component {

    state = {
        item: "",
        quantity: ""
    }

    onButtonPress() {
        this.props.addItem(this.state)
        this.setState({
            item: "",
            quantity: 0
        })
    }

    render() {

    const { input, container, add, addText } = styles;
        return (
            <View style={container}>
                <TextInput placeholder="add item" 
                    placeholderTextColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" 
                    style={input} 
                    onChangeText={item => this.setState({ item })}
                    value={this.state.item}
                />
                <TextInput placeholder="add item" 
                    placeholderTextColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" 
                    style={input} 
                    onChangeText={quantity => this.setState({ quantity })}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={add} onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
                    <Text style={addText}>Add Item</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, {addItem})(AddItem);

const styles = {
    input: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(208, 240, 238)',
        paddingVertical: 15,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        marginBottom: 5
        },
    add: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        paddingVertical: 15,
    },
    addText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white'
    },
    container: {
        padding: 20,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    }
  };
```

Comment: What is the code for `AddItem` ? Also, what is the `<List>` component?

Comment: i added that just now. thank you for looking!

Comment: And the `List` component?

Comment: List is just an included package from react-native-elements: import { List } from 'react-native-elements';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, remove `<List>` from your `ItemsList` since you already use `FlatList`. Then, for your `FlatList` to take up 2/3 of the screen height do this:

```
class ItemsList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.items} 
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <ListItem 
                            name={item.item} id={item.id}
                        />
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString() }
                />
            </View>
          );

        }
    }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { items:  state.items };
  };


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemsList);
```

Comment: thank you! flex 2 is basically saying to only take up 2/3rds of the screen?